# A word or phrase to describe the act of annoying someone by staying close to them and repeating something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

How do you describe it when someone annoys you by repeating something (a favor, question, etc.) over and over *and* standing near you all the time?
I thought of "*to breath down one's neck*", which means *to stay close to someone and watch everything that they do*, but it misses the speaking part.

Comment: Are you trying to ask for a word to describe something that annoys through repetition?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. What's the context of your question? "Repeating something" - tattle-tale or repeated recital? Accidental or on purpose? Your own state - already grumpy or initially happy? etc. Different contexts can generate different answers. Have a look at this [link](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/please-consider-reopening-my-question-trial) about reopening questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider:

> [***keep after***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep%20after)
>   (*informal*):  to tell (someone) again and again to do something:
>   *My kids kept after me to quit smoking, so I finally did.*
>   *I wasn't going to audition, but my friends kept after me.*

Or:

> [***hound***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hound)
>    to chase or bother (someone or something) in a constant or determined way:
>   *They hounded me with questions.*
>   *He is being hounded by the press.*

This is a figurative way of talking about someone who keeps after you, since *hound* is basically a noun meaning *dog*. But there's no special emphasis on the act of talking.

For other options, see [***pester***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pester?searchDictCode=all) and [***its synonyms***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/pester).